# save as picture PNG not the same in excel 2007 and 2021

Tags: excel, image, export-to-image

I changed laptop (from excel 2007 to 2021) and I tried my excel 2007 macro document on a excel 2021. the PNG it generates makes my laser engraver crash.

is there any difference in the format windows 10 / excel 2021 saves PNG VS windows7 / excel 2007?
if so, where are those settings PNG settings?

here is the macro.
Set ws = ActiveSheet
Set shp = ws.Shapes.Range(Array("Group 191"))

```
Set ch = ws.ChartObjects.Add(shp.Left, shp.Top, shp.Width, shp.Height)
shp.Select
ch.Chart.ChartArea.Border.LineStyle = 0
Selection.Copy

ch.Chart.Paste
Set tt = ch.Chart

tt.Export Filename:=ThisWorkbook.Path & "\KP2.png", filtername:="PNG"

ch.Delete
```

also using this macro: https://www.thespreadsheetguru.com/blog/vba-save-as-picture-file-excel
same crash on the laser engraver software when loading the PNG generated with excel 2021. same excel document on 2007, the png does not make the laser engraver crash.

thanks

thanks for you help!

Comment: if I compate both (excel 2007 generated PNG VS excel 2021) I see that the office 2007 is a 32 bits png and office 2021 is a 8 bits. for what it worth... maybe im in the right direction